# @Basic(fetch = FetchType/Lazy) for some TEXT field doesn't work

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to use `@Basic(fetch = FetchType/Lazy)` for the field assigned to the text, although I add a plugin for bytecode enhancement but again selects this text field in query. Does not hibernate give the opportunity to ignore some field? I need this when I select 3 tables, otherwise I know that I can do this with a projection, my structure is one parent and two child with `@OnetoMany` relation.

Answer (score 0):

This requires the use of byte code enhancement. See the documentation for details: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-annotation